# Azure java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "example.core.windows.net.blob.core.windows.net": No address associated with hostname

Tags: android, azure, azure-blob-storage

i am trying to create a blob in azure using the below tutorial project in Android.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android

i have created my own account with free trial and replaced storageConnectionString  using created account name and access key.

```
public static final String storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;"
        + "AccountName=example.core.windows.net;"
        + "AccountKey=firstaccesskey";
```

But i got the below exception:

```
 java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "example.core.windows.net.blob.core.windows.net": No address associated with hostname

The server encountered an unknown failure: 
 Status code 500
```

i am doubting on the storageConnectionString. the way i write the storageConnectionString is rite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use "account" in your connection string and that should take care of the problem. "blob.core.windows.net" will be automatically appended by the SDK.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean it doesn't work sometimes. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: as in, use "account" instead of "accountName"?